# Error:(4) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: android

Whenever i run the app i get this error. I have tried all the solutions online but all of them failed.

Any help?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="dishname"
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textColor="#396fd1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/item_type" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="price"
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="type"
        android:id="@+id/item_type"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/item_nofingredients" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="#"
        android:id="@+id/item_nofingredients"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_type"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_type"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_type" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are missing an opening `<RelativeLayout>` tag.

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG i wrote the beginning of the code in this comment

Comment: Update your post with the full layout's code, not here in the comments. It's hard to read in here.

Comment: it doesn't show up,,, only some part can be viewed!!!

Answer (score 2):

You have 11 invisible [vertical tab characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key) in your XML, the first one at the end of row #4. Vertical tabs are not valid whitespace characters in XML.

Android Studio does not display the vertical tabs. You can use an editor like Sublime Text to see them.

Answer (score 1):

I edited for you.You can copy it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="dishname"
              android:id="@+id/item_name"
              android:textSize="24dp"
              android:textColor="#396fd1"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_alignStart="@+id/item_type" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="price"
        android:id="@+id/item_price"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="type"
        android:id="@+id/item_type"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/item_nofingredients" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="#"
        android:id="@+id/item_nofingredients"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_type"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_type"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_type" />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item_price"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks,,,, i retyped everything and now it is working. Android Studio is full of bugs i believe.